# Why do we care about elements' order if looking for the isomophism types?

Tags: ring-theory, group-isomorphism

I have to exercise several things during the abstract algebra course. Among them is

1. a theorem about finitely generated abelian groups, which says that for a finitely generated abelian group $G$ there are numbers $s,n \in \mathbb{N}_0$, $d_1, \ldots, d_s \in \mathbb{N}_{>1}$ with $d_i \mid d_{i+1}$ for $i \in \{1, \ldots, s-1\}$ and $G \cong Z_{d_{1}} \times \cdots \times Z_{d_s}\times Z_\infty \times \cdots \times Z_\infty$;
2. the fact that $(\mathbb{Z}/ (n))^\times$ consists of all classes $\bar{a}$ so that $gcd(a,n)=1$.

Here $Z_d$ stands for a cyclic group of the order $d$ and $R^\times$ is a unit group of the ring $R$.

Now I have en exercise where I have to determine the isomorphism types for different groups. Reading the solution I do not particularly understand why the order of elements defines the isomorphism types. In particular,

1. $((\mathbb{Z}/(8))^\times = \{\bar{1}, \bar{3}, \bar{5}, \bar{7}\}$, so the types $Z_2 \times Z_2$ and $Z_4$ are possible. The solutions says, **as every element has an order $\le 2$ we have** $(\mathbb{Z}/(8))^\times \cong Z_2 \times Z_2$. I am asking myself where is the bridge, why does it matter, why the order determines the isomorphism type, and why $Z_4$ is not possible.
2. $(\mathbb{Z}/(10))^\times=\{\bar{1}, \bar{3}, \bar{7}, \bar{9}\}$. The solution says, **as $ord(3) > 2$ we have $(\mathbb{Z}/(10))^\times \cong Z_4$**. I have the same questions as above.
3. $(\mathbb{Z}/(15))^\times = \{\bar{1}, \bar{2}, \bar{4}, \bar{7}, \bar{8}, \bar{11}, \bar{13}, \bar{14}\}$. The solution says that **we have three possible types: $Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_2, or Z_2 \times Z_4, or Z_8$**. I agree on that because that corresponds to the theorem. **For the first case all elements must be self-inverse, which does not fit.** I agree, $(2)^{-1}=8$, but how does it link to the isomorphism type? **In the group $Z_8$ there is only one element of the order $2$, which is $a^4$. This does not fit as well.** I agree, we have $(4)^{-1}=4, (11)^{-1}=11$, so there are at least two elements of the order $2$, but how does it link to the isomorphism type? **Finally, we have only $Z_2, \times Z_4$ left, which is the isomorphism type**.

So, could you please explain me what I am missing and explain me that using these three simple examples? I do not understand the logic and the art behind using the order of an element to determine the isomorphism type of a group. I am sad because I miss some basic stuff which seems to be self-evident for the author of this exercise, but I want to learn that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a useful little lemma:

> If $f : A \to B$ is an isomorphism between two groups, and if $a \in A$ and $b=f(a) \in B$, and if $a$ and $b$ have finite order, then the order of $a$ equals the order of $b$.

Here's the proof. Let $m$ be the order of $a$ and let $n$ equal the order of $b$. It follows that
$$\text{Id}_B = f(\text{Id}_A) = f(a^m) = f(\underbrace{a a \ldots a}_{\text{$m$ times}}) = \underbrace{f(a) f(a) \ldots f(a)}_{\text{$m$ times}} = \underbrace{b b \ldots b}_{\text{$m$ times}} = b^m
$$
and therefore $n \le m$ (of course there's really an induction argument hidden here, in which one proves that $f(a^i)=b^i$ for all $i \ge 1$). Similarly, using the inverse isomorphism $f^{-1}$, one proves that $m \le n$. Therefore $m=n$.

As a corollary, if $A,B$ are isomorphic groups, and if $A$ has ***no*** elements of order $4$, then $B$ also has ***no*** elements of order $4$. This should settle your $(\mathbb Z / (8))^\times$ example.

I'm sure you can now figure out how to apply similar logic to the other examples (and, please, [only one question per post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#33671)).

And, by the way, the statement of that lemma is unnecessarily weak. If you look at it's proof, you'll see that something stronger is proved, namely you do *not* need to assume that $a$ and $b$ have finite order. The proof shows that if $a$ has finite order then so does $b$, and if $b$ has finite order then so does $a$, and therefore $a$ has finite oder if and only if $b$ has finite order.

Comment: Maybe it's useful for OP's future to also consider an "obvious" generalization of the lemma: If $f: A \rightarrow B$ is *any* group homomorphism, and $a \in A$, then $ord(f(a)) \le ord(a)$.

Comment: I did not know that the isomorphism goes that deep. I would argue a bit different, because the lines says $b^n = b^m$ which implies $n \mid m$ and $n \le m$. I will take into account about the "one question per post", thank you for pointing me on that. I keep confused only about $Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_2$ group. How can $(0,1,1)$ be self-inverse? Do we use addition in $Z_2$ instead of multiplication?

Comment: Regarding your question in the comments, when one says for example that there is an isomorphism $f : (\mathbb Z / (8))^\times \to Z_2 \times Z_2$, in the domain one is using the operation $\times$ and in the range one is using the coordinate-by-coordinate operation $+$. One could, if one liked, express each of those $Z_2$ groups in the range as $(\mathbb Z / (2))^+$.

Comment: ok, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

1. If every element of a group $G$ has an order $\le2$, $G$ can't be (isomorphic to) $(\mathbb Z_4,+)$ because in $\mathbb Z_4$ there are elements of order $4$.
2. If some element of a group $G$ has an order $>2$, $G$ can't be (isomorphic to) $(\mathbb Z_2,+)^2$ because in $\mathbb Z_2^2$ every element has an order $\le 2$.
3. Being not self-inverse is equivalent to having an order $>2$.
   If a group $G$ has at least two elements of order $2$, $G$ can't be (isomorphic to) $(\mathbb Z_8,+)$ because the latter has only one element of order 2.
   Btw, the elements of order 2 in $(\mathbb{Z}/(15))^\times$ are not $\bar7^{-1}=\bar{13}$ but $-\bar1=\overline{14}$, $\bar4$ and $-\bar4=\overline{11}$.

Comment: Oh, true, that is a mistake, thank you! The elements of the order 2 are $\bar{4}, \bar{11}$ and $\bar{14}$.